# VB.net console application to print Reverse of number

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to print reverse of number using VB.NET console application and I have variable of type Integer. when I give  number 651 as input it prints 1561. I have write code as

```
Sub Main()
    Dim no, rev, temp As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("enter the no")
    no = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    rev = 0
    temp = no
    While temp > 0
        Dim t As Integer
        t = temp Mod 10
        rev = rev * 10 + t
        temp = temp / 10
    End While
    Console.WriteLine("Reverse number=>"+rev.ToString())
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

when I enter number 123 then it gives proper output as 321, but when i give 678,it give output 8761 or other garbage value, please suggest me suggetion

Comment: So what does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: Uhm, `String.Join("", no.ToString().Reverse())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting such result because,

> when you assign a division result to an integer value it will
>   automatically get rounded to the next higher integer.

For example `Dim no As Integer = 68 / 10` will give you result as `7`, 
if you are coding with `Option Strict On` then this casting is not allowed.
The best way is suggested by **Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå** you can simply reverse a number and print it.

```
Console.Write("Reverse of {0} is : ", no.ToString().Reverse())
```

or else you can follow the following steps:

```
    Console.WriteLine("enter the no")
    Dim no As Integer = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
    Console.Write("Reverse of {0} is : ", no)
    While no > 0
        Console.Write(no Mod 10)
        no = Math.Floor(no / 10)
    End While
    Console.ReadKey()
```

Comment: Its really work. It also work with the code that I write above as 
        temp =Math.Floor( temp / 10)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `\` instead of `/` and your work is done.